# Weird lock up in the kernel

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, llvm, clang

Basically, I'm messing around with loading and linking object code into the Linux kernel from mach object files, and I've noticed something weird when I do a `printk` from inside that object. If I call printk with over 3 (4 or more) arguments (`printk("%d,%d,%d \n", 1, 1, 1)`), the system will lock up, but at some point later (it will not return from the system call and just lock up instead). **The actual print works and prints the expected values in all cases.**

Now, the weird thing is that **this only happens when I build it using Clang+LLVM**. Here is the culprit code:

[image: Bad Clang]

On the other hand, when this is built using LLVM GCC, it works just fine:

[image: LLVM GCC]

This also works when built with GNU GCC:

[image: GNU GCC]

**Can anyone suggest a reason for why the clang version makes the system lock up?** So basically, there is something wrong with the first snippet of code that makes it lock up that isn't present in the others. I don't really know what's wrong.

Comment: Probably scrobbling of something important somewhere.  Where exactly, I have no idea. Any chance of stepping through it instruction by instruction?

Comment: Wait, you're loading code from *Mach* object files? Explain?

Comment: @duskwuff Long story short, I wrote a linker to link and load mach object files into the linux kernel. The linker isn't the issue, everything else works just fine.

Comment: Whoa. Well. Are you sure your Mach object uses the same calling conventions as the Linux kernel?

Comment: @duskwuff Not entirely sure. But I think EABI and Darwin ABI are pretty similar. I've changed EABI slightly so large types are now 4-byte aligned for compatibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know how you generated the object files, but it seemsthat you're using Darwin ABI, which is basically heavily modified APCS ("old" ARM ABI). However, for linux et al you need to use EABI (aka AAPCS), which differs from APCS in many cases.

For example, R9 is call-saved in EABI, but call-clobbered on darwin, there are differences in passing 64 bit values, etc. Note that your clang example clobbers R9, while llvm-gcc - does not :)

Comment: Yes! It was the `r9` issue, because the trap handler does not expect it to be trashed. I made sure that it saved `r9` on the stack before branching to the handler code, which fixed the issue.